# How to disable content type HTML in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

I'd like to receive all my emails with content-type `text/plain` by default while using Gmail (no clients), by default Gmail uses content-type `text/html`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "receive as plain"? You want gmail.google to send your browser plain text when you ask to see a message body? If you actually mean "receive into my inbox only plain text", you unfortunately don't get to choose what some sender across an SMTP link sends.

Comment: @msw some messages are sent with multiple content types (`multipart-messages`). When a `multipart-message` is sent to gmail, the web interface choose  the `text/html` over the `text/plain` body. I'd like to receive only the `text/plain` version if present.

Answer (score 7):

When you receive email in gmail, gmail honors the "text/html" body part if one is present.
I do not think there is any way to disable this behavior if you are using gmail's web interface.

However, for mail that is "sent from gmail", this is easily do-able:

I checked my gmail, and it is sending mail with:

> ```
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
> ```

My Gmail "Settings --> General" has this enabled:

> ```
> Outgoing message encoding: Use default text encoding for outgoing messages
> ```

And when I compose a message in gmail, I make sure I am using "plain text" for my email.

Comment: Well, maybe a filter would do the trick; forward all the incoming email to self with `content-type: text/plain` and then removing the original message. (maybe tagging the original message with a new html label would work).

Comment: "maybe a filter would do the trick" -- if you are talking about using the native web-based gmail client, you cannot remove or modify email headers from a filter...

Comment: @joyjit, **10 years has passed**. any update?

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to use the mobile version of gmail, [m.gmail.com](http://m.gmail.com).

Comment: Thanks but It wouldn't work for me, I'd like to review the emails from the gmail's web interface.